# First join tables on column then run query on multiple columns, to reduce data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables.

- A small (70kb) table containing 100 URLs in `webhistory.dom100.100domains`.
- A large table `httparchive.sample_data_2020.response_bodies_desktop_10k`) with columns "page" and "body".

I would need to query "body" in the HTTPArchive table, but only where "page" is one of the 100 URLs in the "100domains" table.

If I use this below, it still seems to crunch all 20GB of "page" and "body" in the HTTPArchive sample table. That is the full "body" column in that table, and since I need to do this on the real HTTPArchive data and multiple tables, I need to minimize query data volume. Is there a way to reduce the query to just the overlap between the two tables?

```sql
with maintable as (
  select NET.HOST(page) as dhost, body 
  from `httparchive.sample_data_2020.response_bodies_desktop_10k`
)  
select body, dhost 
FROM maintable 
JOIN `webhistory.dom100.100domains` ON maintable.dhost= `webhistory.dom100.100domains`.host;
```

I am new to BigQuery, and I am using the web console.

Comment: Not sure how that helps.

Comment: I don't know this database, but can you create a table (or a temporary table) that contains the overlap between the tables? Perhaps that will perform better with the query you are wanting to run.

Comment: To reduce query volume a fixed filter on the partition column may help. Joining does never reduce the query volume. For getting started: query without the body column, but with the partition column of the large table and obtain a range for the real query with the body column.

Comment: There is no easy way to optimize your query, as far as I can see. If you want to look for some specifics values in a non partitioned table, bigquery will have to read all records. The way I see to reduce the data volume is: add an primary key on the big table, make your search selecting only the dhost and return the keys. With the keys, search the body by the id. Then you can reduce the volume of data read .